# Reddit's commenting system (hierarchial)

Tags: comments, reddit, hierarchical-trees

For those of you who have looked at Reddit's source code, where exactly is the logic where it manages the comments hierarchial structure?

I downloaded the code, but couldn't even find the database structure let alone where the reads and writes are for the commenting.

Is it doing updates on lots of comments if someone replies to someone mid-way through a thread?

Answer (score 3):

The class definition for the Comment model is in [r2/models/link.py](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/master/r2/r2/models/link.py#L591) .

Comment: it looks to be using recursion?